# new $this->table() vs. new tablename(); dynamic class generation

Tags: php

I have the following classes:

```
namespace database;

class database {
    protected $table = '';

    function __construct()
    { // Stuff here }

    public function all() {
        // Load from database
        // Return array with results
    }
}

class tbl_organisation_types extends database {
    protected $table = 'tbl_organisation_types';

    function __construct($data = [])
    {
        parent::__construct();
        // do stuff with $data
    }
}
```

I fetch all rows from the database, iterate through them and create new objects. Since other classes extend this `database` class, the generated objects have to be dynamic.

When i try to generate the objects dynamically like this

```
$return[] = new $this->table($row);
```

I get the following error

> Uncaught Error: Class 'tbl_organisation_types' not found in /path/to/tbl_organisation_types.php

If I generate the objects with a fixed classname like this it works. But then it wouldn't work for multiple classes.

```
$return[] = new tbl_organisation_types($row);
```

Is there a way to dynamically generate objects and/or why is mine not working?

Using `PHP 7.1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am getting an impression, that you are attempting to create something like [active record](https://www.martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/activeRecord.html) there. I would advise against that.

As for why your class is not working, you probably should do something like:

```
$name = '\\database\\' . $this->table; 
$instance = new $name($row);
```

When you use a string to initialize class, it has to contain the *fully qualified class name*, no matter in which namespace your code is. And same applies even to aliases.